Playwright hangs forever on page.reload()
This is the Java code that is used:
public void waitForOrReload(Page page, Locator locator) {
    try {
        debug("waitForOrReload");
        locator.waitFor(new Locator.WaitForOptions().setTimeout(5000));
    } catch (PlaywrightException e) {
        debug("Reloading because of PlaywrightException: %s", e.getMessage());
        page.reload();
        debug("waitForOrReload again");
        locator.waitFor(new Locator.WaitForOptions().setTimeout(5000));
    }
}

I'm not sure if this is the right way to retry, but instead of writing the code differently, I want to learn and understand what could be going wrong.
The code is running using env var DEBUG=pw:api.
It's running in a docker container in a gitlab-ci pipeline, and when the website-under-test is slowing down (>5s), the exception is thrown. The page should then be reloaded. There are no options given to the reload method, so it should have a default timeout of 30s as per https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-page#page-reload. I checked if I overwrite that timeout somewhere, but I don't afaik.
Usually, the code runs fine, but every now and then, the pipeline hangs until gitlab makes it fail. In that case, this is what is logged:
2024-10-26T10:46:03.275Z [DEBUG] waitForOrReload
2024-10-26T10:46:03.276Z pw:api => Locator.waitFor started
2024-10-26T10:46:03.364Z pw:api waiting for getByLabel(Pattern.compile("foo")).first() to be visible
2024-10-26T10:46:08.371Z pw:api waiting for navigation until "load"
2024-10-26T10:46:08.367Z pw:api <= Locator.waitFor failed
2024-10-26T10:46:08.368Z [DEBUG] Reloading because of PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='Timeout 5000ms exceeded.
  name='TimeoutError
  stack='TimeoutError: Timeout 5000ms exceeded.
    at ProgressController.run (/tmp/playwright-java-7909686021559017509/package/lib/server/progress.js:78:26)
    at Frame.waitForSelector (/tmp/playwright-java-7909686021559017509/package/lib/server/frames.js:619:23)
    at FrameDispatcher.waitForSelector (/tmp/playwright-java-7909686021559017509/package/lib/server/dispatchers/frameDispatcher.js:106:103)
    at FrameDispatcher._handleCommand (/tmp/playwright-java-7909686021559017509/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:94:40)
    at DispatcherConnection.dispatch (/tmp/playwright-java-7909686021559017509/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:365:39)
}
Call log:
- waiting for getByLabel(Pattern.compile("foo")).first() to be visible
2024-10-26T10:46:08.368Z pw:api => Page.reload started
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 6h0m0s seconds

The logs that confuse me are the last 2.
Just before failing, it says:
pw:api => Page.reload started

However, this is where it hangs until it fails a few hours later (because gitlab kills the job). I'm not sure what happens between those 2 events. I tried stracing the process, but I'm not sure if I'm stracing the correct one (there are a few instances of chrome binary).
Assuming this is an strace of the right process: strace spams the console with -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable), maybe that is related?
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 14) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2fd404513d68, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x2fd404513cd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
sendto(121, "\10\0\0\0h\0\0\0\30\0\24\0\0\0\0\0\201\24)\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 104, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 104
sendto(121, "\10\0\0\0h\0\0\0\30\0\24\0\0\0\0\0\202\24)\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 104, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 104
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 1 ([{fd=15, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
read(15, "!", 2)                        = 1
sendto(121, "\10\0\0\0h\0\0\0\30\0\24\0\0\0\0\0\203\24)\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 104, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 104
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 1) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 28) = 1 ([{fd=15, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
read(15, "!", 2)                        = 1
getrandom("\xd4\xa6\xf8\x20\x16\x5a\x03\xdb", 8, 0) = 8
getrandom("\xbc\x38\x05\x20\x0f\x94\xe8\xcc", 8, 0) = 8
futex(0x2fd404513d6c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
recvmsg(19, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(35, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=35, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 1 ([{fd=15, revents=POLLIN}])

I'm unable to reproduce it locally, so I need a bit of luck to have it happen in the gitlab pipeline.
Any ideas on how to figure out what is happening here?
I tried to figure out what is happening using strace, I checked dmesg, but none of those show clear hints afaik.
